# How to incrementally calculate `sha256` for a file which is uploaded to multiple server instances?

Tags: python, hash, sha256, hashlib

I want to provide a file-upload API which supports uploading a big file by multiple http requests.  The requests can go to different servers, but I don't want to have the whole file copied to all those servers - they should accept the file fragment and forward it to another service, but I somehow need to get the SHA256 checksum from the individual parts before that.
ds?

In Python, I know `hashlib` can call `update` to calculate the `sha256` signature step by step, but that obviously requires the steps to execute in the same Python process.

Could anyone help me figure out how to continue calculating sha256 during http requests for a big file when the parts are not all available to the same Python instance at the same time?

Comment: What is your actual question? The `update` function does exactly what you seem to be asking, precisely for this reason.

Comment: @tripleee I can do update in one http request,which can check the sha256 value of the body send in this http request. but I want to check the sha256 value of the total file ,not by doing  sha256  restart when finish the requests.

Comment: Again, the `update` method of `hashlib` exists precisely so that you can feed it the file in smaller pieces. If it's not working like you hope, please [edit] to provide a small [mre] (perhaps take a 4-byte file and submit it one byte at a time as a minimal demo).

Comment: @tripleee I know ,by calling update again ,could do sha256,but,in different requests,how I can get the sha256 value had done,and continue to do update when I get the body in the next request.

Comment: Are you actually trying to ask how to communicate the intermediate result between different ... threads? processes? servers? If it's not possible to retain the object in memory between calls, you'll need to figure out a way to serialize it. `pickle` comes to mind. But it's really not clear if that's actually your question.

Comment: (If you don't know how to use the comma character, you will probably be easier to understand if you don't use it at all.)

Comment: @tripleee，Sorry. Different servers. May be ,the pickle part will be ok.I will have a try.At the start, I hope here has any method to export and load the hashlib's middle/tmp data,to continue the sha256,in the next request.

Comment: @tripleee, pickle can not work. I will try to find any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer from this link: https://bugs.python.org/issue11771

It suggests a third-party library called [rehash](https://github.com/kislyuk/rehash) for sharing the intermediate `hashlib` object between Python instances.